# Symfony 4 - How to embed form with multiples entites?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

I'm new to Symfony 4 and I need to make a form with multiples entities.

**The goal is to be able to ask a question and associate it with several tags.**

I have a ManyToMany relation. Each tag can appear in several questions, and each question has several tags.

To translate this relation, I created a **Hashtag entitie** with (for the moment) this structure :

- question_id
- tag_id

My **Question entitie** has theses properties:

- title
- body

And my **Tag entitie** has just :

- name

Of course, with the relations, my Question entitie has get, add and remove hashtags.

The problem is I don't understand how I must do to fetch my tags. I managed to do this one time but using Entitytype. However I didn't work when I submitted my form.

But if I understand, I must have a CollectionType. I tried this in my **QuestionType form** :

```
->add('hashtags', CollectionType::class, [
                'label' => 'Choose tags',
                'entry_type' => TagType::class,
                'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
            ])
```

I have 0 error, but it just shows me my label with nothing else.

What is missing ? Must I also change something in my twig template ?

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}    
    <button class="btn">{{ button_label|default('Create') }}</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Thx for your help !!

Comment: With `CollectionType` you always create a new Tag Entity. you should use `EntityType` and configure it to create the non-existent tags.

Comment: BTW. `CollectionType` needs to add custom HTML and jQuery to provide the visible interface. https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#basic-usage